# How do I continue playing Soul Reaver on PS1 when it hangs?

Tags: technical-issues, soul-reaver

I'm playing Soul Reaver on Playstation 1 and in some locations the game freezes and never continues. How do I keep playing when it happens?

Comment: I don't believe this is a problem that anyone's going to have anymore.  If they're going to be playing Soul Reaver, chances are high they'll be playing it through PSN.

Comment: Over the last three months I heard four different people say how interesting the game was back in the days, and how they struggled with this exact issue, so I felt like posting this, at least just so people knew this could be fixed.

Comment: Thing is, though, that this is a problem that people *used* to have.  Arqade is about problems people are having *right now*.  We're not here to be a repository for problems that are no longer problems.  Indeed, we close questions about problems that are no longer problems.

Comment: I don't know the exact number of people who still play their ZX Spectrum games, but sure, I'll let the community decide if this is never going to be a problem for anybody in the future.

Comment: Perhaps we should generic this to be possible solutions to the console freezing?  Unless you actually continue to get this problem with Soul Reaver, anyways.  In which case, I withdraw my objection.

Comment: In Spyro it happened to me like four times, in a specific spot. Not sure about the other spots, it hasn't happened to me in years there. In Soul Reaver it has a lot of places because of the game's continuous level design throughout most of the game. And I do still play my other old games on ps1, yes, including Soul Reaver.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try opening the CD tray and closing it. The game then unhangs and continues as usual. You may stop hearing the music for a little bit, but it should restore and keep playing.

This trick is not very well known, but it helps with this specific game.

Comment: This is generally useful, but not specific to this game. I'm not sure about the details, but I think opening and closing the CD tray makes the console refresh something, and somehow it helps. I bet some random speculation here will help this comment sound legitimate.

Comment: @kalina I don't think your sarcasm is necessary, or makes you sound like a nice person. Or adds something useful to the post. I was just explaining possible reasons for why this solution works, and it really does work.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the user1306 answer you may also want to clean the reading part of the system. It's the little bulb which you can wipe with some cotton **make sure it's not wet**. Otherwise it will break the system.

Comment: This is generally useful, but not necessarily with this specific game. I'm not sure about the details, but I think it's some kind of reading overhead or cache error that causes this hang, and opening the CD tray makes console refresh something, and somehow it helps. I bet the developer kit had more memory somewhere than the consumer version, so the devs might not have had this problem.